# Xamarin.Forms issue with button with border?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have this button:

```
 <Button x:Name="btnNext" BorderWidth="2" BorderColor="#96AF5B" BorderRadius="4" 
                WidthRequest="110" HeightRequest="25" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                BackgroundColor="#FFFCFF" FontSize="Default"

                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Width,Factor=0.5, Constant=-55}"

                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
            ElementName=videoPlayer,Property=Height,Factor=0.85, Constant=12.5}"  FontFamily="verdana"
                    Clicked="Next_Clicked"/>
```

in Android, it shows a little square at the top left side of the button when tapped, this also happens when using a frame instead of setting the button's border properties.

here's a gif:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGv5j.gif

Comment: If you use frame, did you try setting the IsClippedToBounds property to true?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this bug has been around for a while now if I am not wrong we started facing this issue around somewhere in mid of March and it has been there ever since.

If you check Bugzilla there are a ton of bugs that have been logged for all the issues that people are facing because of this:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58140

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42351

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60248

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60392

So I went out and devised a workaround which seems to be working fine for us using Label and Stack layout with some customized changes:

```
  public class CustomButton: Label   
  {
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomButton), null);

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CustomButton), null);

    public event EventHandler ItemTapped = ( e, a ) => { };

    public CustomButton()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    private ICommand TransitionCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                AnchorX=0.48;
                AnchorY=0.48;
                await this.ScaleTo(0.8, 50, Easing.Linear);
                await Task.Delay(100);
                await this.ScaleTo(1, 50, Easing.Linear);
                Command?.Execute(CommandParameter);

                ItemTapped(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            });
        }
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command=TransitionCommand
        });
    }
}
```

I have also added a little animation so it gives the feel for a button.

Then use this Label as follows:

```
 <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="1"> // Here padding will be the border size you want and background color will be the color for it 
      <nameSpace:CustomButton XAlign="Center" BackgroundColor="Blue" /> //Height and Width request is mandatory here
 </StackLayout>
```

The only problem with this solution is that you cannot add border-radius.